# Hosted Payment Page transaction returning 'Error: 302'

Tags: transactions, global-payments-api

When going through the flow of making a payment via the GlobalPayments Hosted Payment Page, entering the card details and clicking 'pay now' returns:

```
Error: 302 
Message: Merchant details not configured correctly.
```

We are using the PHP and JS sdk to format the correct JSON and direct to the HPP.
I haven't been able to find anywhere in the docs that mention an error code '302'. Is there any way to get more information on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Good Day! I would contact customer support (ecomsupport@globalpay.com). We can verify your merchant account details are correct and appropriately configured for use with the HPP. They may request some code samples or the JSON generated for the HPP, which should not be shared through Stack Overflow.